# How does IOTA post-coordicide handle network spam?

Tags: spam-attack

Is spam protection already implemented in the latest devnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is already implemented in goshimmer since v0.6.3. The IOTA Congestion Control Algorithm (ICCA) used in IOTA 2.0 is based on mana. More in this blog post:
https://blog.iota.org/explaining-the-iota-congestion-control-algorithm/